# kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

kubectl is installed correctly but the expose does not work what am I missing here ?

```
shivam@shivam-SVS151290X:~$ cat ~/.kube/config
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/shivam/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.99.100:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/shivam/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/shivam/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key
shivam@shivam-SVS151290X:~$ kubectl
kubectl controls the Kubernetes cluster manager.

 Find more information at:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/

Basic Commands (Beginner):
  create        Create a resource from a file or from stdin.
  expose        Take a replication controller, service, deployment or pod and
expose it as a new Kubernetes Service
  run           Run a particular image on the cluster
  set           Set specific features on objects

Basic Commands (Intermediate):
  explain       Documentation of resources
  get           Display one or many resources
  edit          Edit a resource on the server
  delete        Delete resources by filenames, stdin, resources and names, or by
resources and label selector

Deploy Commands:
  rollout       Manage the rollout of a resource
  scale         Set a new size for a Deployment, ReplicaSet or Replication
Controller
  autoscale     Auto-scale a Deployment, ReplicaSet, or ReplicationController

Cluster Management Commands:
  certificate   Modify certificate resources.
  cluster-info  Display cluster info
  top           Display Resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage.
  cordon        Mark node as unschedulable
  uncordon      Mark node as schedulable
  drain         Drain node in preparation for maintenance
  taint         Update the taints on one or more nodes

Troubleshooting and Debugging Commands:
  describe      Show details of a specific resource or group of resources
  logs          Print the logs for a container in a pod
  attach        Attach to a running container
  exec          Execute a command in a container
  port-forward  Forward one or more local ports to a pod
  proxy         Run a proxy to the Kubernetes API server
  cp            Copy files and directories to and from containers.
  auth          Inspect authorization

Advanced Commands:
  diff          Diff live version against would-be applied version
  apply         Apply a configuration to a resource by filename or stdin
  patch         Update field(s) of a resource using strategic merge patch
  replace       Replace a resource by filename or stdin
  wait          Experimental: Wait for a specific condition on one or many
resources.
  convert       Convert config files between different API versions
  kustomize     Build a kustomization target from a directory or a remote url.

Settings Commands:
  label         Update the labels on a resource
  annotate      Update the annotations on a resource
  completion    Output shell completion code for the specified shell (bash or
zsh)

Other Commands:
  alpha         Commands for features in alpha
  api-resources Print the supported API resources on the server
  api-versions  Print the supported API versions on the server, in the form of
"group/version"
  config        Modify kubeconfig files
  plugin        Provides utilities for interacting with plugins.
  version       Print the client and server version information

Usage:
  kubectl [flags] [options]

Use "kubectl <command> --help" for more information about a given command.
Use "kubectl options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all
commands).
shivam@shivam-SVS151290X:~$ **kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080**
Error from server (AlreadyExists): pods "**hello-minikube" already exists**
shivam@shivam-SVS151290X:~$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "**hello-minikube" not found**
shivam@shivam-SVS151290X:~$
```

Comment: What is Kubernetes version?

Comment: kubectl version << ?

Comment: Could you please share the output of the commands:  `kubectl get deployments -A` ` kubectl get pods -owide -A` and `kubectl get svc -A`. What is the Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: shivam@shivam-SVS151290X:~$ kubectl get deployments -A
NAMESPACE     NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   coredns   2/2     2            2           57d
shivam@shivam-SVS151290X:~$ kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE     NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP                  57d
kube-system   kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   57d

Comment: shivam@shivam-SVS151290X:~$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.4", GitCommit:"c96aede7b5205121079932896c4ad89bb93260af", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-17T11:41:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:50:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Please update your question with the output of the command `kubectl get pods -A`. By the command you shared must be a `hello-minikube` running, but i can see in the commands above.